# Initializing specific indices from a very large int array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

I want to create a very large array and fill some of them with other standard-values than 0 , right when im creating them.
How can I do this from the beginning?

I know how it works with primitives with int MyInt = 12;

But now I want to change the value of the array in the index: 123,
Every other value should start with  0.

```
public static class Arrays
{
    public static bool[] Bools = new bool[20000];
    public static int[] Integers = new int[20000];
    public static float[] Floats = new float[20000];

    //Integers[123] = 100; This obviously doesnt work.
}
```

Comment: put your code into static constructor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) of the class to initialize static members:

```
public static class Arrays
{
    static Arrays()
    {
        Bools =  new bool[20000];
        Floats = new float[20000];
        Integers = new int[20000];
        Integers[123] = 100;
    }

    public static bool[] Bools;
    public static int[] Integers;
    public static float[] Floats;
}
```

Comment: it does seem a shame that the indexer collection initializer syntax doesn't work here... imagine `= new int[20000] { [123] = 100 };`

Comment: @MarcGravell: would be nice, but tbh i've never really missed it. Could be confusing